# Creating Dynamic UI using React

Tags: dynamic, reactjs, components

I have following use case:

1. I have set of react components
2. User add those components from some gallery to page
3. User configure those components and favorite the view
4. User can configure those components and favorite one more view
5. User click on of the favorite items from his setting and it loads the page with corresponding configuration.

   I am wondering using react how can I achieve this. How can I construct page dynamically using react components?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that:

> **React** is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces. It uses a
>   declarative paradigm that makes it easier to reason about your
>   application and aims to be both efficient and flexible.
>
> **JUST THE UI**
>
> Lots of people use React as the V in MVC. Since React makes no
>   assumptions about the rest of your technology stack, it's easy to try
>   it out on a small feature in an existing project.

Given that, react components just show the `data` that you pass on. You can construct the page dynamically based on the `data`. This is usually passed on using `props`.

*e.g.*

> `<CustomInput type="text" />` and inside it can return a component/html >based on its `type`.
>
> `<List items={this.props.items} />` and an `item` can be an `object` >`{name: 'item name', type: 'item type'}` and you will map it to  >`<CustomInput type={item.type} name={item.name}/>`

So it all depends on how you handle your data and your plan on how to show it in the front-end.

### For your current scenario

You can have a `Gallery` component that have your Component collection that sets the `props` of the components inside the `Page`

```
// components prop of Page is an array of React Components
const arrayOfComponents = [{type: 'One', name: 'Component-One'}, {type: 'Two', name: 'Component-Two'}, {type: 'Three', name: 'Component-Three'}];
<Container>
    <Gallery>
        <AddReactComponent type="One" />
        <AddReactComponent type="Two" />
        <AddReactComponent type="Three" />
    </Gallery>
    <Page components={arrayOfComponents} />
</Container>
```